# File Path in Variable -> File identifier in File Content for Power Automate Flow

Tags: power-automate

So I have this flow step and I want to replace hardcoded value of **file identifier**
with variable.

(Point where I call variable)
[image]

(How variable looks like)
[image]

Hardcoded path works, I tried it.

I want to set hardcoded path into variable and use it in steps like variable.

Comment: Sorry but what’s the problem?

Comment: *File identifier* -> If you are type /Shared Documents/ER_Bussines_Trip_Test it works.
But if you set it to a variable as a string and call the variable to *File identifier* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two operations for retrieving file contents, you need to use the right one when you want to use.

I created a basic variable with a file name ...

[image: File Name]

... and then tested with both types of `Get file content` operations in the `SharePoint` group.

You need to use the `Get file content using path` operation.

[image]